# PHP mongodb installation issue

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I have issues in PHP-Mongodb Linux installation. After following the below steps, I am not able to access webpages instead it's getting downloaded.

1) Installed MongoDB PHP driver 
  sudo pecl install mongo

2) Added mongo.so to /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 directory

3) Added "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini file

4) restarted XAMPP
   sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

Environment: Linux Mint 14 - 64 bit

If I try commenting step 3, I can access it but getting mongo class not found exception. Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are there errors in your PHP logs indicating that the extension could not be loaded successfully? It's also possible that the path in which you're placing it isn't accessible or searched by PHP. Using the full path to the mongo.so file in the `extension=` declaration could fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through below provided link step by step.

http://enginedave.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/install-mongodb-php-driver-to-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same issue

Download and install XAMPP devel package first. If you installed XAMPP in /opt folder then use the below command or You can replace /opt/ to the path where you installed XAMPP.

## tar xvfz xampp-linux-devel-1.x.x.tar.gz -C /opt/

Note: Download and install the appropriate version then only it works.